# Classes and modules in ruby

Tags: ruby, class, module

Can you tell me where we should use modules and where classes? I mean what is the usability and applicability principle for modules in Ruby?

Comment: you should check out this Ruby Rogues podcast for some answers - 
[When to use Modules](http://rubyrogues.com/022-rr-when-to-use-modules/)

Answer (score 1):

*Modules are collections of methods and constants. They cannot generate instances. Classes may generate instances (objects), and have per-instance state (instance variables).
Modules may be mixed in to classes and other modules. The mixed-in module's constants and methods blend into that class's own, augmenting the class's functionality. Classes, however, cannot be mixed in to anything.
A class may inherit from another class, but not from a module.
A module may not inherit from anything. --[Ruby FAQ](http://www.rootr.net/rubyfaq-8.html)*

Classes are reliable abstractions with only what matters and Modules are containers that can give me informations or services and furthermore can be a place to keep singularity. For example, we could classify shy people and timidity be a singularity of this classification. ShyPeople may be a class and Timidity a module included in ShyPeople class.

'What matters?','Is it a module's method or a class' method?' or 'will it be a class or a module?' are questions that only experience and RL's analogies can help you. For more details I recommend to you reading and coding :)

Answer (score 0):

My simple rule of thumb is if I need to keep the inner state of an object, for example creating instance variables, I will use a class.
I use modules for everything else.  This includes namespacing, mixins and utility objects.

[some basic Namespacing and Mixin info](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, a Ruby module is like a class, but without the factory of objects part. Usually Ruby developers use modules to store groups of methods that have to be used by more than one class. This is, among other things, a great way to avoid using subclasses, that are very anti-rubyist pattern.

Anyway, that's almost a philosophical question that one can't answer properly in a short way. Maybe you should try to read a book about the Ruby basics (for example, Eloquent Ruby).

Answer (score 0):

Classes **ARE** modules. The difference is that a class can be instantiated.

The usage of both is really dependent of how your class/module will be used, what it represents, ...

There are no ultimate answers to this question. In any case (imho), that is something you learn by reading and writing code, learning about idioms, design patterns, ...

Answer (score 0):

In ruby, a module consists of methods,variables, and constants, similar to classes, just that it lacks the ability to be instantiated.

Modules are typically included or extended inside classes depending on how you want to expose and use methods it contains. You include a module if you want its methods, variables and constants to be made available in every object of the class you included it in. You extend a module if you want its methods, variables and constants to be made available to the class and NOT TO instances of the class.

Ruby classes employ single inheritance, that is, a class has ONLY one parent class/superclass. However, ruby allows you to "sort of" mimic multiple inheritance by including modules in your classes and this concept is referred to as mixins.

Answer (score 0):

Modules are used as namespaces and as mixins. Ruby does not support multiple inheritance. However, there are cases where a class would benefit by acquiring methods defined within multiple other classes. That is made possible by using a construct called module. A module is somewhat similar to a class, except it does not support inheritance, nor instantiating. It is mostly used as a container for storing multiple methods. One way to use a module is to employ an include or extend statement within a class. That way, the class gains access to all methods and objects defined within the module. It is said that the module is mixed in the class. So, a mixin is just a module included in a class. A single module can be mixed in multiple classes, and a single class can mix in multiple modules; thus, any limitations imposed by Ruby's single inheritance model are eliminated by the mixin feature.

All modules are instances of the Module class.

```
module Foo
end

Foo.instance_of? Module  # Output: => true
```

In the following example, the JapaneseGreetings module is included (as a mixin) in the Person class.

```
module JapaneseGreetings
  def  hello
    puts "Konnichiwa"
  end

  def goodbye
    puts "Sayōnara"
  end
end

class Person
  include JapaneseGreetings
end

p = Person.new
p.hello  # Output: Konnichiwa
p.goodbye  # Output: Sayōnara
```

### Classes are modules

All classes are instances of a built-in class called Class? Well, Class is a subclass of Module (another built-in class).

```
Class.superclass  # Output: => Module
```

Most of the built-in methods used to manipulate classes are defined in the Module class.

```
Module.instance_methods(false)
 => [:<=>, :module_exec, :class_exec, :<=, :>=, :==, :===, :include?, :included_modules, :ancestors, :name,
 :public_instance_methods, :instance_methods, :private_instance_methods, :protected_instance_methods, :const_get,
 :constants, :const_defined?, :const_set, :class_variables, :class_variable_get, :remove_class_variable,
 :class_variable_defined?, :class_variable_set, :private_constant, :public_constant, :singleton_class?,
 :deprecate_constant, :freeze, :inspect, :module_eval, :const_missing, :prepend, :method_defined?, :class_eval,
 :public_method_defined?, :private_method_defined?, :<, :public_class_method, :>, :protected_method_defined?,
 :private_class_method, :to_s, :autoload, :autoload?, :instance_method, :public_instance_method, :include]
```

It is standard practice to implement "generic" code (which can be used in different contexts) in the superclass and add extra specialization within subclasses. An example is how the Class class inherits all the above instance methods from the Module class and implements three additional methods.

```
Class.instance_methods(false)
 => [:new, :allocate, :superclass]
```

The allocate method allocates memory and creates a new "empty" instance of the class, without calling the initialize method. The new method calls allocate, then invokes the initialize method on the newly created object. As for superclass, it returns the name of the superclass of a given class.

In his book The Ruby Programming Language, Yukihiro Matsumoto (the creator of Ruby, AKA Matz) demonstrates how the new method would look like if it were written in Ruby:

```
def new(*args)
  o = self.allocate # Create a new object of this class
  o.initialize(*args) # Call the object's initialize method with our args
  o # Return new object; ignore return value of initialize
end
```

In brief, we might say that classes are modules with two significant extra functionalities: inheritance and instantiation. Another difference is that, unlike modules, classes cannot be used as mixins.